# Kotlin how to create default object when find returns null

Tags: kotlin

What is the "kotlin-way" to create a default object if find function returns null?

```
val address = this.addresses.find { a -> a.principal }
```

Should I conver `address` to variable and use a conditional like if/else?

Comment: Elvis operator. `this.addresses.find { a -> a.principal } ?: defaultValue`

Answer (score 5):

```
val address = this.addresses.find { a -> a.principal } ?: Address()
```

If left is null then right value will be assigned.

Comment: In fact, the right-hand side won't even be _evaluated_ unless the left-hand side gives null; it short-circuits in a similar way to `&&` and `||`.  In this example it won't create a new `Address` instance unless it's needed.